Why is the second or looped select() blocking?
I'm getting blocked at a select() while working with a pipe.  The first select() will unblock when we get data on stdin (I just type one letter and press Enter).
Then I write data to the write-end of a pipe, but the select() doesn't recognize any data on the pipe's read fd.  So it blocks indefinitely.
int    fd_pipe[2];
char   buf[20];
fd_set set;

pipe(fd_pipe);

FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(fd_pipe[0], &set); // Pipe read fd
FD_SET(0         , &set); // stdin fd

select(fd_pipe[0]+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL); // I type 1 char + ENTER to get past this point

if (FD_ISSET(0, &set))
{
    read(0, buf, 20);          // Can confirm we do get here
    write(fd_pipe[1], buf, 1); // Lets put just one character in the pipe
}

select(fd_pipe[0]+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL); // <-- We get stuck here

if (FD_ISSET(fd_pipe[0], &set))
{
    char d;
    read(0, &d, 1);
    assert(d == buf[0]);
}

If I do this without select(), things work fine:
int fd_pipe[2];
pipe(fd_pipe);

char c = 'x';
write( fd_pipe[1], &c, 1);

c = 'a';
read( fd_pipe[0], &c, 1);

assert(c == 'x');

In the larger picture, I have a multi-threaded program which is using select() and pipe() to emulate canceling a read() operation.  I write to the pipe with a single character with the intent of forcing select() to return so I can shutdown the operation instead of trying to send a signal to cancel a blocking read() on the main FD.  But select() doesn't return.

I think you'll need to reset that fd_set before every select() call.

See Is it necessary to reset the fd_set between select() system calls?

The select function modifies the sets you pass to it. When select return the sets will contain only the active descriptors.
In your case only STDIN_FILENO will be set, so the second call to select will not have fd_pipe[0] in it.
The solution is actually not to re-add the pipe to the set and call select a second time, but to only call select once:
FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(fd_pipe[0], &set); // Pipe read fd
FD_SET(0         , &set); // stdin fd

select(fd_pipe[0]+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL); // I type 1 char + ENTER to get past this point

if (FD_ISSET(0, &set))
{
    read(0, buf, 20);          // Can confirm we do get here
    write(fd_pipe[1], buf, 1); // Lets put just one character in the pipe
}
else if (FD_ISSET(fd_pipe[0], &set))
{
    char d;
    read(fd_pipe[0], &d, 1);
    assert(d == buf[0]);
}


You also need to check what select actually returns. It could return -1 which means there's an error.

If you do need to call select more than once.  Then you'll need to re-zero/re-set the fd_set.

The pipe FD won't be ready after I called select the first time, because I wrote after the first select.  Does this mean, I should FD_ZERO and FD_SET before each call to select()?

@Stewart Use a loop?

And yes, absolutely checking the return value of select,  didn't include that in the MCVE though.

In my man page, the wording describing this is: "After select() has returned, readfds will be cleared of all file descriptors except for those that are ready for reading."

Fantasitc.  Just found another man page which says: "Note well: Upon return, each of the file descriptor sets is modified in place to indicate which file descriptors are currently "ready".  Thus, if using select() within a loop, the sets must be reinitialized before each call."
